# How to make my app not to link to some lib? `QT -= `?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, linker, qmake

So  I try to compile my app statically. anf I do not link my app to  `QtScript.lib` in my  pro file. but something does. I compile using MSVC compiler. I wonder how to say in `.pro` file that my app shall not be linked to some library?

Comment: See variable [LIBS](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs) which contains a list of libraries to be linked into the project and [Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#qt) which controls which of the Qt modules are used by your project.

Answer (score 0):

QtScript is a dependency for a number of other Qt libraries, like WebKit, and obviously QtScriptTools. Also QtDeclarative depends on QtScript if I'm not mistaken.